# Set Table Attribute Dynamically

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I am trying to set the `TableAttribute` for my view like so:

```
[Table(LSODatabase.databaseString)]
```

However the following error is thrown:

```
An attribute argument must be a constant expression, typeof expression or array creation expression of an attribute parameter type.
```

A workaround I am trying to avoid is making another view and manually setting the strings, however I have a lot of views and would like to avoid this as much as possible.

Comment: The `TableAttribute` is meant to be applied to your EF entity classes, not to views.

Comment: What should be applied to my views?

Comment: Views are basically templates that generate html/js/(other text) - I've never encountered anyone applying attributes to views.

Answer (score 0):

The error is somewhat self explaining. The arguments you put into your attribute constructors have to be a constant expression, typeof expression or array creation expression. The databaseString field of your LSODatabase isn't constant unless you add the const modifier. Constant means that you can say at compile time what the value of the property will be and that it won't be able to change at runtime.

Comment: Right, however my question is how I can work around this as I need to dynamically set the string.

Comment: @TheShield You cannot. The C# compiler just doesn't allow this.

Answer (score 0):

As the error says, you must use either a `constant`, a `typeof` expression or an array creation.

One possible solution would be:

```
public class LSODatabase
{
    public const string databaseString = "myDatabase";
}
```

Now you can use that as an argument for your attribute.

Comment: This won't do as I need to be able to change the string.

Comment: Yes, that is not possible - as the error states. And frankly, it doesn't really make sense to want to be able to change the table name at runtime.